# Automatic dependency injection handle exception laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

Here is my case

I have cron job(console command)

```php
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(OrdersMagentoService $magentoService)
    {
        try {
            $orders = $magentoService->getRemoteOrders();
            print_r($orders);
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            $this->line('Error connect to soap api, error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            die;
        } catch (\Throwable | \Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            die;
        }
    }
```

In `handle` method i automaticaly inject `OrdersMagentoService`, this service do connect to magento soap api and exctend from `BaseMagentoService`

```php
class OrdersMagentoService extends BaseMagentoService
{
    public function getRemoteOrders()
    {
        $complex = [
            'complex_filter' => [
                [
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' =>
                        [
                            'key' => 'in',
                            'value' => 'closed,canceled,holded,processing,complete'
                        ]
                ],
                [
                    'key' => 'updated_at',
                    'value' => [
                        'key' => 'from',
                        'value' => now()->subDays(200),
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $this->salesOrderList($complex);
    }
}
```

```php
class BaseMagentoService
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository|mixed
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * BaseMagentoService constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = config('services.magento');
        $this->connect();
    }

    /**
     * Do connect to soap api v2
     *
     * @throws \SoapFault
     */
    private function connect()
    {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->getApiUrl());
        $this->session = $this->client->login($this->config['user_name'], $this->config['password']);
    }

    public function __call($resource, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->client->$resource($this->session, ...$arguments);
    }
}
```

In `BaseMagentoService` constructor i create connection to magento soap api. But if connection throw error(for example wrong username and pass) then i can't handle this in cron job file. I understand that laravel at first create `OrdersMagentoService`, it throw error and `try catch` in `handle` function not works, but i dont know how to fix this.

I can add in `handle` method

```php
        try {
            $magentoService = resolve(OrdersMagentoService::class)
            $orders = $magentoService->getRemoteOrders();
            print_r($orders);
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            $this->line('Error connect to soap api, error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            die;
        } catch (\Throwable | \Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            die;
        }
```

And remove automatic DI, and tit should work well, but i dont want to do it.

Also if i add some `try catch` in `connect` method of `BaseMagentoService` then i cant log this error in my cron job.

What is best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would switch the handling from the artisan command to a Job or an Event that might be more suited to the problem. Then your artisan command simply fires off this new job or event each time is executed.

This is also somehow stated in the docs as a best practice:

> For greater code reuse, it is good practice to keep your console commands light and let them defer to application services to accomplish their tasks.

Then if you look at the documentation about jobs, there is a section about error handling for failed jobs where you are told that you can define a method that gets triggered once he job has failed. Example excerpt taken from the docs:

```php
class YourJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param  AudioProcessor  $processor
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AudioProcessor $processor)
    {
        // Process uploaded podcast...
    }

    /**
     * The job failed to process.
     *
     * @param  Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
    }
}
```

You can read more [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs). There is also a paragraph about global jobs failure handling that might suit your use case

Comment: Thx for you answer, it can help me, but reason why I don't want use job for this - I can't use good logging during job runs, I don't see any '$this->line' method in job class which can write logs in my log file for command(I added it when set up schedule) do you know how I can resolve it?

Comment: You can use the Log facade to write messages to log files (under `resources/logs`) with 8 different levels of output. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#writing-log-messages). You could also create a new channel for the console logging that outputs in a different file from the web application one and configure it that for certain error levels the logging gets reported to multiple systems like slack for example. If you have more concerns about it were might open a chat on SO and discuss further if you want